# how do i pivot list of object and create new list in linq c#?

Tags: c#, linq, pivot-table

I have a list of employee work hours data by day. I want to pivot day and hours data and create a new list of object with employee name, and series of days with respective hours as value.

My list looks like

```
List<EmployeeHour> employeeHours = new List<EmployeeHour>
{
new EmployeeHour{Id = 1, EmployeeName = "Emp1", Day = 1, Hours = 6},
new EmployeeHour{Id = 1, EmployeeName = "Emp1", Day = 2, Hours = 8},
new EmployeeHour{Id = 2, EmployeeName = "Emp2", Day = 1, Hours = 6},
new EmployeeHour{Id = 2, EmployeeName = "Emp2", Day = 2, Hours = 8}
};
```

I want to create new list of the object where Hours dsomething like

```
new {
   Id = 1,
   EmplyeeName = Emp1,
   Day1 = 6,
   Day2 = 8
},
new {
   Id = 2,
   EmplyeeName = Emp2,
   Day1 = 6,
   Day2 = 8
}
```

This is how i did it. Is there better solution?

```
  dynamic d = new
                    {
                        Employee = group.FirstOrDefault().EmployeeName,
                        Day1 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.DayNumber == 1)?.HoursPerDay,
                        Day2 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.DayNumber == 2)?.HoursPerDay,
                        Day3 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.DayNumber == 3)?.HoursPerDay,
                        Day4 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.DayNumber == 4)?.HoursPerDay,
                        Day5 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.DayNumber == 5)?.HoursPerDay,
                        Day6 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.DayNumber == 6)?.HoursPerDay,
                        Day7 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.DayNumber == 7)?.HoursPerDay
                    };
list.Add(d);
```

Comment: There are many similar question here. There's no standard one-line solution.

Comment: This is how I did it sir.
  dynamic d = new
                    {
                        Employee = group.FirstOrDefault().EmployeeName,
                        Day1 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.DayNumber == 1)?.HoursPerDay,
                        Day2 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.DayNumber == 2)?.HoursPerDay,
                       
                    };

Comment: Do you need the days to be dynamic?  If so, why not have a distinct list of employees each with their own list of days and hours?

Comment: I am using datatables.net plug in to create the table. This is only one way i know how to populate the data on ajax call in datatables.net jquery by mapping the column with returned objects. So i chose that way. You can guide me the best way to do it. I chose the plugin because it restructure the table to fit in for the small devices.

Comment: Ok, so you want your table to have "Day 1", "Day 2" columns to a specific number of days?

Comment: I think you can return a Dictionary value instead of a class for this.  Instead use List<Dict<string, object>>() and then you have your rows and variable length column names.  If you go the other route, it's best to have a hard typed class with a specific number of days predetermined and return that class, otherwise if you're working with variable length data, you might just want to transform the list of data from C# in your javascript code instead.  I'll give an answer.

Comment: I am not working with variable length data. But i would like to know how do i do it if its variable length data. I would be grateful.

Comment: You'd do it through using a dictionary instead of an anonymous class.

Comment: What is `group`? How was it created? Why are you setting `d` to be `dynamic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a dictionary.

C# is a strongly typed language so variability in class properties is limited.  What appears to be better suited in your case is a `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```cs
var dictionaries = employeeHours.Select(x => new {x.Id, x.EmployeeName})
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"Id", x.Id},
        {"EmployeeName", x.EmployeeName}
    })
    .ToList();

foreach (var dict in dictionaries)
{
    var id = (int)dict["Id"];
    foreach (var dh in employeeHours.Where(x => x.Id == id))
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey("Day" + dh.Day))
        {
            dict["Day" + dh.Day] = dh.Hours;
        }
    }
}
```

This code will give you a dictionary of variable lengths, and when this is transformed using JSON, it should give you the data structure you need in datatables.

Comment: Seems like a lot of code that could be replaced by a `GroupBy` and `Select`.

Comment: @NetMage - the solution is simple and straight forward and easy to read for this beginner.  However let me consider your insight for a `GroupBy`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result to be a statically typed anonymous (or defined class) object, you will need to do something like what you are doing.

I would use an enhanced dictionary type converted from each group to make it easier to extract the values:

```
//***
// Enhanced Dictionary that returns default(TValue) for missing values
//***
public class NullDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {
    public NullDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> d) : base() {
        foreach (var kvp in d)
            Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
    public NullDictionary() : base() { }

    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TryGetValue(key, out var val);
            return val;
        }
        set
        {
            base[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

With an extension method to make creation easy:

```
public static class DictExt {
    public static NullDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToNullDictionary<T, TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> keyFn, Func<T, TValue> valFn) {
        var nd = new NullDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var s in src)
            nd.Add(keyFn(s), valFn(s));
        return nd;
    }
}
```

Now you can pivot the data using `GroupBy` and extract the anonymous objects:

```
var ans = employeeHours.GroupBy(eh => new { eh.Id, eh.EmployeeName }, eh => new { Day = $"Day{eh.Day}", eh.Hours })
                         .Select(pg => {
                             var pd = pg.ToNullDictionary(p => p.Day, p => (int?)p.Hours);
                             return new {
                                pg.Key.Id,
                                pg.Key.EmployeeName,
                                Day1 = pd["Day1"],
                                Day2 = pd["Day2"],
                                Day3 = pd["Day3"],
                                Day4 = pd["Day4"],
                                Day5 = pd["Day5"],
                                Day6 = pd["Day6"],
                                Day7 = pd["Day7"],
                            };
                         })
                         .ToList();
```

It is also possible to use a more dynamic object, such as a `DataTable`, or a `Dictionary` or `ExpandoObject` for each list member, or even to create an anonymous object at runtime, though that is of questionable value most of the time since you can't easily access its fields. However, if you did not know how may `Day` values may be possible, and want to handle a varying number, you must use one of these or replace the day fields with a collection of some sort instead (e.g. an array, list, or dictionary).

Comment: All this kid wants is a data structure he can read in datatables.js.  This seems a bit over engineered for the need. XD. But it is interesting to see your approach nonetheless.

Comment: @PaulCarlton That wasn't clear from the original question which I based my answer on :) Or maybe I think everything is a nail and extension methods are my hammer of choice. I can't wait for extension everything.

Comment: Hah! :)  For me extensions have its place, as long as it doesn't get in the way of mocking tests, extensions are great for simplifying dtos and adding neat syntactic sugar around repetitive tasks.